# parse Xdocument to Open XML word processing document

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I have one xml string I have created that using string some string functions.

eg.

```
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="002F03B5" w:rsidP="002C6BC9" w:rsidRDefault="003A1CA9"><w:pPr><w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0" /><w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0" /><w:adjustRightInd w:val="0" /><w:contextualSpacing /><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr><w:t>Given below is a schematic break-up of the phases/stages of cell cycle.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="002F03B5" w:rsidP="002C6BC9" w:rsidRDefault="003A1CA9"><w:pPr><w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0" /><w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0" /><w:adjustRightInd w:val="0" /><w:contextualSpacing /><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:color w:val="FF0000" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">        </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="0022219F"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:noProof /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr><w:drawing><wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0"><wp:extent cx="1085850" cy="1533525" /><wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="0" r="0" b="0" /><wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="D:\Common Folder\scan\biology\10.cell cycle and cell division\topic no 1 q no 10.jpg" /><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1" /></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:pic ><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 1" descr="D:\Common Folder\scan\biology\10.cell cycle and cell division\topic no 1 q no 10.jpg" /><pic:cNvPicPr><a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1" /></pic:cNvPicPr></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="IB10Q17Q0" cstate="print" /><a:srcRect /><a:stretch><a:fillRect /></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr bwMode="auto"><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0" /><a:ext cx="1085850" cy="1533525" /></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst /></a:prstGeom><a:noFill /><a:ln w="9525"><a:noFill /><a:miter lim="800000" /><a:headEnd /><a:tailEnd /></a:ln></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic></wp:inline></w:drawing></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidRPr="00B35FE2" w:rsidR="002F03B5" w:rsidP="002C6BC9" w:rsidRDefault="003A1CA9"><w:pPr><w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0" /><w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0" /><w:adjustRightInd w:val="0" /><w:contextualSpacing /><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" /><w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr><w:t>Sample application xml generated for testing?</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body</w:document>
```

Now I want to load this xml file in open x document.

parse Xdocument to Open XML word processing document 
Can any please help me for this?

Hope for reply.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: HI,Please please help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

To create a DOCX document you have to put this XML in a ZIP file according to Open Packaging Conventions (OPC) specification. Take a look at the following articles by Eric White to find out the details how OPC works. http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/opc-expanded